# How to assign array with the values of the entered in textfiled in ipad

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an iPad app and I want to enter the values of textfield` inputs in an array and then perform a calculation. I am using the following code:

```
myPieClass.itemArray=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"5",@"10",@"15",@"20",@"30", nil];
myPieClass.myColorArray=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:[UIColor purpleColor],[UIColor redColor],[UIColor orangeColor],[UIColor yellowColor],[UIColor greenColor], nil];
myPieClass.radius=100;
```

The above code gets static values, I want to get values from textfield.

```
NSString*value1=textFieldOne.text;
```

and then give this value to array and so on for other textfiedls i have three textfields.

Comment: if you will make any calculation the objects in your array must be int, which my answer gives you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myPieClass.myTextFieldArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects: textField1.text, textField2.text,  textField3.text,  textField4.text, nil];
```

or

```
NSString *value1 = textField1.text;
NSString *value2 = textField2.text;
NSString *value3 = textField3.text;

myPieClass.myTextFieldArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:value1, value2, value3, nil];
```

Comment: Can we save the graph in pdf file in iPhone app

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your textfields are `tf1`, `tf2`, `tf3`.

```
NSString*value1=tf1.text;
NSString*value2=tf2.text;
NSString*value3=tf3.text;
    NSMutableArray *array= [NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[value1 intValue], [value2 intValue], [value3 intValue], nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answers are correct, but here is a better example:

```
myPieClass.itemArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:textField1.text,
                                                 textField2.text,
                                                 textField3.text, nil];
```

Assuming your itemArray property is declared as retain you may want to pass it an autoreleased object to avoid leaks.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSInteger *value1 = [textField1.text integerValue];
NSInteger *value2 = [textField2.text integerValue];
NSInteger *value3 = [textField3.text integerValue];

myPieClass.myTextFieldArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:value1, value2, value3, nil];
```